# Laravel maatwebsite/excel package, import even duplicate columns

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to import an excel file which is having some duplicate "columns/fields", note: duplicate "columns" not duplicate "rows/records".

For example - I have 2 columns named "cash", only one of the column is imported. How can I import all such duplicate columns.

Comment: it's better if you show your code and a screenshot of your case, to help us understand your problem better.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.